# use Parameters bei DLLImport from C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem to use parameters from a DLL which was built in Labview.

My whole Code is:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public class Program
    {

        //DLL einbinden
        [DllImport(@"C:\DLL_Uebergabe\SharedLib.dll")]
        public static extern void Unbenannt2(out double Amplitude, out double Reqlength);


        public void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Einbinden der .Net Interop-Assembly
            //double Amp;
            //Result Amplitude = new Result();
            //Amp = Amplitude.GetResult();
            //Console.WriteLine("Amplitude ist demzufolge: {0}", Amp);

            double Amplitude;
            double Reqlength;
            this.Unbenannt2(out Amplitude, out Reqlength);
            Console.WriteLine("Amplitude: {0} und Reqlength: {1}", Amplitude,Reqlength);

        }
    }
```

}

My Compiler always said:

"cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualified it with a type name instead."

This error raises at code line:

this.Unbenannt2(out Amplitude, out Reqlength);

Can you please tell me the mistake? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call it without the `this.` pointer, because it is not an instance member; it's a static member.

Comment: @SteveBene: would you be so kind to accept one of the answers, so the question can be marked as close?

Answer (score 1):

Ahaha!! public **static** extern . Simple use Program.Unbenannt2 or Unbenannt2.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler is telling you that your method is a `static` method, and you are trying to access it as if it was an *instance* method. [This means is doesn't belong to an instance of your `Program` class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645766%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

You can *qualify it with a type name instead*, as compiler suggested:

```
Program.Unbenannt2(out Amplitude, out Reqlength);
```

Or, since it belongs to your `Program` class anyway, you can simply omit the type name:

```
Unbenannt2(out Amplitude, out Reqlength);
```